# COM exception was unhandled in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Automation Element using:

```
var automationElement = AutomationElement.FromPoint(location);
```

And I am geting error.

COM exception was unhandled:
An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL))`

Can any one help me out with this please.....

Comment: Does this help?? http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/SLN61289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely a threading issue. If your program is trying to find an element in its own user interface you need do it in a separate thread. Give this a try:

```
var automationElement;
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    automationElement = AutomationElement.FromPoint(location);
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
// now automationElemnt is set
```

Comment: It's possible to use a task instead of a Thread:

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
 automationElement = AutomationElement.FromPoint(location);
}).Wait();

Answer (score 1):

It is working for 1st time but after that it is not working....

I have use mousehook to get property of object on mouse click. Here is code.

```
    private  AutomationElement GetAutomationElementFromPoint(Point location)
    {


        AutomationElement automationElement =null;

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            automationElement = AutomationElement.FromPoint(location);
        });

        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        return automationElement;
    }

     private void mouseHook_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement element = GetAutomationElementFromPoint(new System.Windows.Point(e.X, e.Y));

        //Thread.Sleep(900);
        if (element != null)
        {

           textBox1.Text =  "Name: " + element.Current.Name + " ID: " + element.Current.AutomationId + " Type: " + element.Current.LocalizedControlType;
        }
        else
           textBox1.Text = "Not found";
    }
```

On 1st click it is giving values, but on next click it gives blank values even if element is not null.

What can be problem?